# Using ternary operator inside MYSQL query in PHP syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I have this simple PHP/MYSQL prepare statement:

```
$DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM books '.($_POST['author'] ? '' : '').'
               WHERE id = '1'");
```

The ternary operator above leads to a syntax error. The error is related to using the post variable `$_POST['author']`.

I tried changing it to:

```
$_POST[\'author\']
$_POST[\"author\"]
$_POST["author"]
```

All of the above didn't work.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your ternary operator has the same result either way. And what is `$_POST['author']`? A number? A `TRUE`/`FALSE`?

Comment: what is it author? table? data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quotes are mismatched.

```
$DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM books ".($_POST['author'] ? '' : '')." WHERE id = '1'");
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap the php in double quotes:

```
$DBH->prepare("
  SELECT * 
  FROM books " .($_POST['author'] ? '' : ''). " 
  WHERE id = '1'
");
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are using " at first, and then '.

"string' needs to be "string" or 'string'

Answer (score 0):

i think you cannot use question mark inside a prepare() as it may consider it as a bind variable.

instead use

```
$author = $_POST['author'] ? '' : '';
$Sql = "SELECT * FROM books.$author WHERE id = 1";
$DBH->prepare($Sql);
```

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

Anyway ...

If we supose $_POST is the author table you should do something like

$_POST['author'] = "authors"

In your code using ($_POST['author'] ? '' : '') is much better to use $_POST['author'] with table of authors.

And then select clausule should be like:

$table = $_POST["author"];
$DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM books b INNER JOIN $table a ON b.author_id=a.id WHERE b.id = 1");

If we supose what you set in the post variable in the index you have to do:

$index = $_POST["author"];
$DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM books  WHERE author_id = $index");

It should work, but anyway, you should give us more information

tables for both option I thought are::

books is id, author id, ...
author is id